# How to adjust axes to domain in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a 2d function over a rectangular domain which is not a square. When I save the plot to pdf, the axes do not match the borders of the rectangular domain and there are two white stripes above and below the domain as shown in the below image

[image]
How do I get rid of the white stripes while still using plt.axis('equal')?

Here is a minimal code example (plotting a linear function instead):

```
def fun(x,y):
   return x+y;

x_lower = 0
x_upper = 10
y_lower = 0
y_upper = 5

x = np.linspace(x_lower,x_upper,500)
y = np.linspace(y_lower,y_upper,500)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = fun(X,Y)

plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,10,cmap='pink')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks([x_lower,x_upper])
plt.yticks([y_lower,y_upper])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('linear.pdf')
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code example? Besides `'auto'`, or `'equal'`, the `set_aspect()` method of the `Axes` object accepts a number to set the aspect ratio manually, maybe that helps. See here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect

Comment: @ Nils L. : Thanks for this hint. Replacing plt.axis('equal') by ax.set_aspect('equal') does the trick.

Comment: I wonder why this is necessary, I would have expected that the `plt.axis()` function internally calls the `set_aspect()` method of the `Axis` object and does more or less the same thing ...